# Как закрепить текст внизу и по центру блока. Адаптивно, а не методом подбора

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

На изображении видно текст-ссылку "Read More" . Нужно закрепить его именно по центру дива .col-md-4 . Пробовал использовать absolute и подбирал left/right, но при изменении масштаба экрана блоки меняют свой размер, а текст остается на прежней позиции. На каждые 10 пикселей я же не буду менять координаты. Какие есть варианты?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: 2 картинка]

Comment: каким образом вы подбирали left и зачем меняли right? Судя по картинке, вам нужно чтобы левый край текста был по середине.
Должно работать с `position:absolute;left:50%` никаких right,bottom,top, не нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы закрепить по центру можете воспользоваться:

```
margin-right: auto; 
margin-left: auto;
```

Comment: работает только для блочных элементов.

Comment: Судя по картинке, нужно левый край по центру, а не сам текст.

Comment: Не работает такое )

Answer (score 1):

Я вижу у вас там зачем-то position: absolute, но пусть так.
Попробуете дать ссылке bottom: 0, left: 50%; transform: translatex(-50%);

Comment: Да, ваш вариант работает! Но почему, блин?) Что это за translatex и почему не работает другими более естественными способами?)

Comment: Скажу честно, я бы сделал не так как вы... Мы уже боремся с последствиями ваших решений.

Comment: Можно намекнуть на способ по-лучше?)

Comment: Выкинуть бустрап и все сделать самому, на flex. )))

Comment: Я только учусь и в данный момент учу Bootstrap) Пока сам не в восторге , но знать нужно =)

Comment: бутстрап знать абсолютно не нужно. за его знания много не заработаешь. нужно все руками + подтянуть пару моментов по флексам - профит )

Answer (score 1):

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.clear,.clear:after,.clear:before{
  content:'';display:block;clear:both;
}
.wrapper{
  width:100%;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.wrapper .a,.b,.c{
  width:30%;
  text-align:justify;
  float:left;
  margin:10px .8% 14px 2%;
}
.link{
  clear:both;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper clear"> 
    <div class="a"> 
     <p> 
Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Proin eget tortor risus. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt.      
    </p>
    <div class="link"> 
      <a href="#">read more</a>
    </div>
   </div>
    <div class="b"> 
     <p> 
Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Proin eget tortor risus. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt.      
    </p>
    <div class="link"> 
      <a href="#">read more</a>
    </div>
   </div>
    <div class="c"> 
      <p> 
Vivamus suscipit tortor eget felis porttitor volutpat. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet et, porttitor at sem. Vivamus magna justo, lacinia eget consectetur sed, convallis at tellus. Proin eget tortor risus. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt.      
    </p> 
    <div class="link"> 
      <a href="#">read more</a>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Демо на :[Codepen.io](http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/OXEYWZ?editors=1100)